# Setting up Socket.io with 404's

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, npm

I have a LAMP server where I'm running apache and server.js, I also have an index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var socket = io();
        </script>  
    </body>
    <style>
    html, body {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: #333;
    }
    </style>
</html>
```

---

In the console, I'm getting the error:

**http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LJ0ESOW Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

---

I'm using npm install socket.io to install Socket.io for the server (node), and npm install Socket.io-client for the client which I should be able to run in my normal java script browser!

What's the issue? Am I installing wrong?

Comment: On what port is `server.js` listening?

Comment: The port is 8000, Im running the server via [node server.js] and running the index.js via xampp (apache)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `socket.io` server is listening on `localhost:8000`, you need to retrieve the client code from there:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Otherwise, the client is being requested from Apache, which doesn't have the correct handler for that URL.

The client should also be pointed to the correct server location:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:8000');
```

Comment: Yah I figured it out its because npm was naming it socket.io-client and Iw as referring to socket.io, thanks though!

Comment: @Robinlemon you don't need `socket.io-client` if you are already using `socket.io` (the server); the latter already includes the client.